# Unable to login into Ejabberd while use blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, ejabberd

I am getting following error while trying to login into Ejabber using blazemeter a Jmeter pulgin:

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLErrorException: SASLError using DIGEST-MD5: text
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:348) ~[smack-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.login(XMPPTCPConnection.java:244) ~[smack-tcp-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.xmpp.actions.Login.perform(Login.java:51) ~[jmeter-plugins-xmpp-1.5.1.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say anything meaningful without seeing your [XMPP Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/xmpp/XMPPSampler.md) configuration and full *jmeter.log* file contents, the most possible reason is that you provide wrong `Resource` which doesn't match what ejabberd expects.

Consider adding the next line to [*log4j2.xml* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="com.blazemeter.jmeter.xmpp" level="debug" />
```

this way you will have way more information regarding outgoing and incoming packets.

Also check out [XMPP Load Testing - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xmpp-load-testing-the-ultimate-guide/) article which provides comprehensive instructions on Jabber servers load testing using JMeter.

Comment: Do servers actually validate the resource name at all? I had the impression it can be literally any label to distinguish the client.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below to user properties in JMeter and restart to get it working:

```
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```